# Full Calender not working with angular code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I'm using ashraw's fullcalendar for an event scheduler in my project, and to display the events I have to write the code in jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
   //editable: true,
   events: [{
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: '2014-06-01'
    }
]});
```

The above works fine if I attach it to a simple html page with all client side dependencies.

But if I want  use the same code with in AngularJs. Then the above doesn't seem to work... I'm not sure what the problem is, and how to solve it ...

Here my events will bind from node.js's rest service:

```
    MyFirstMeanApp.controller('LeaveController', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookieStore', 
                function ($scope, $http, $cookieStore) {

        var Events = [];

        $http({
           method: 'POST',
           async: false,
           url: 'http://localhost:3000/GetDataForEvents',
           data: {
            userID: $cookieStore.get('credentials')._id
           }
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              Events = JSON.stringify(data);                  
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    dayClick: function (date) {
                        if (date < new Date()) {
                           alert("You can't set an event in past date..");
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.$apply();
                            $('#test_modal').modal('show');
                        }
                    },
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    events:  Events 
              });
            })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert("error");
        })
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your jquery plugin with a $timeout:

```
app.controller('LeaveController', function($scope, $timeout,...) {
    ...
     $timeout(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({...});
     });

});
```

Most jQuery plugins require the DOM to be ready, but in Angular there is no DOM ready.  But you can get the equivalent of DOM ready by executing code inside of a $timeout handler.  The reason is because the $timeout callback is executed after the view is rendered (i.e. the $digest phase)